# What is the correct date format for the following date example: "2018-06-06 14:03:57.973468 +00:00"

Tags: php, laravel, date, timestamp, laravel-nova

I'm using PHP with laravel nova to create my models in the database. My database already have its data, but I have some issues to insert values in columns from the date type.

My database is a pgsql that stores date in this format: `2018-06-06 14:03:57.973468 +00:00`

But when I try to create a row in my via Laravel nova admin, it's try to insert the following date formart: `2018-12-22 14:00:00+`

The date formart is missing the miliseconds and the timezone, I would like to know witch date format I have to set in my `$dateFormat` variable:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s+';

public function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d H:i:s+';
}
```

As you can see in the code I'm using `Y-m-d H:i:s+` format, but it only works when I get the date from the DB, when I try to insert a row it returns the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "2018-12-21 14:00:00+" (SQL: insert into "offer" ("column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "column_name", "created_at") values (, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 2018-12-21 14:00:00+, 2018-12-22 14:00:00+, 283, 2018-12-13 15:44:03+, 2018-12-13 15:44:03+) returning "id")
```

#### EDIT 1

I updated the date formart to `Y-m-d H:i:s.u P`, and the error changed. I check if the date and the date formart match using the following function:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u P')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}

validateDate('2018-06-06 14:03:57.973468 +00:00'); // => true
validateDate('2018-06-06 14:03:57.973468 +00:0022'); // => false
```

And the error change to `Unexpected data found. Data missing`

Comment: Remove the plus sign to start with. You can see how to format dates with https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. If you pass in the date in a proper format (without the +) it should convert it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you are using Laravel, try using Carbon to handle it.

Example with tinker.

```
>>> use Carbon\Carbon;
>>> $date = Carbon::parse('2018-06-06 14:03:57.973468 +00:00');
=> Carbon\Carbon @1528293837 {#3039
     date: 2018-06-06 14:03:57.973468 +00:00,
   }
>>> $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
=> "2018-06-06 14:03:57"
```

Also remove the `+` sign, because you are not passing the timezone in the time format.

Comment: laravel is using carbon by default for formatting declared date fields like `created_at` & `updated_at`

Comment: @YagoAzedias what do you mean by date format? when you do this `$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` you provide the string with the format that you want `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`, although when you do `$date = Carbon::parse('somedate');` you can call several number of ISO or RFC formats available `$date->toIso8601String();` https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats

Answer (score 1):

use the `Y-m-d H:i:s P` format.

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s P';

public function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d H:i:s P';
}
```

you can check all the formats available on http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I tried it but does not seems to work too, for what I saw in the link 'c' format is for date like this: `2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00` but my case is different: `2018-06-06 14:03:57.973468 +00:00`

Comment: i updated my answer. you just need the `_P` after the format you had from the start

Comment: In this case I getting a `The timezone could not be found in the database`. Maybe I also have to set the mileseconds?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the milliseconds. how are you setting your data in the database ? are you using the eloquent methods or you have your own ?

Comment: Like i said: "My database is a pgsql that stores date in this format: 2018-06-06 14:03:57.973468 +00:00" plus the column's type is "timestamp with time zone"